# Setting the language for \IfLanguage

Tags: cross-referencing, babel, languages, cleveref

In my preamble I have

```
\RequirePackage{cleveref}
% Set names with both of the following
%   \crefname{environmentname}{singular}{plural}, to be used mid-sentence
%   \Crefname{environmentname}{singular}{plural}, to be used at the beginning of a sentence
\IfLanguageName{english}{
    \crefname{table}{table}{tables}
    \Crefname{table}{Table}{Tables}
    \crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}
    \Crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}
    \crefname{equation}{equation}{equations}
    \Crefname{equation}{Equation}{Equations}
    \crefname{paragraph}{paragraph}{paragraphs}
    \Crefname{paragraph}{Paragraph}{Paragraphs}
    \crefname{subparagraph}{subparagraph}{subparagraphs}
    \Crefname{subparagraph}{Subparagraph}{Subparagraphs}
}{}
\IfLanguageName{ngerman}{
    \crefname{table}{Tabelle}{Tabellen}
    \Crefname{table}{Tabelle}{Tabellen}
    \crefname{figure}{Abbildung}{Abbildungen}
    \Crefname{figure}{Abbildung}{Abbildungen}
    \crefname{equation}{Gleichung}{Gleichungen}
    \Crefname{equation}{Gleichung}{Gleichungen}
    \crefname{paragraph}{Abschnitt}{Abschnitte}
    \Crefname{paragraph}{Abschnitt}{Abschnitte}
    \crefname{subparagraph}{Unterabschnitt}{Unterabschnitte}
    \Crefname{subparagraph}{Unterabschnitt}{Unterabschnitte}
}{}
```

Right after `\begin{document}` I have `\selectlanguage{english}` and my first line is `\documentclass[article, english]{llncs}`, but when I use `cleveref`, the German is used nonetheless. What am I doing wrong? What do I need to change?

---

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\RequirePackage{iflang}
\RequirePackage{cleveref}
\IfLanguageName{ngerman}{
    \crefname{table}{Tabelle}{Tabellen}
    \Crefname{table}{Tabelle}{Tabellen}
    \crefname{figure}{Abbildung}{Abbildungen}
    \Crefname{figure}{Abbildung}{Abbildungen}
    \crefname{equation}{Gleichung}{Gleichungen}
    \Crefname{equation}{Gleichung}{Gleichungen}
    \crefname{paragraph}{Abschnitt}{Abschnitte}
    \Crefname{paragraph}{Abschnitt}{Abschnitte}
    \crefname{subparagraph}{Unterabschnitt}{Unterabschnitte}
    \Crefname{subparagraph}{Unterabschnitt}{Unterabschnitte}
}{}
\IfLanguageName{english}{
    \crefname{table}{table}{tables}
    \Crefname{table}{Table}{Tables}
    \crefname{figure}{figure}{figures}
    \Crefname{figure}{Figure}{Figures}
    \crefname{equation}{equation}{equations}
    \Crefname{equation}{Equation}{Equations}
    \crefname{paragraph}{paragraph}{paragraphs}
    \Crefname{paragraph}{Paragraph}{Paragraphs}
    \crefname{subparagraph}{subparagraph}{subparagraphs}
    \Crefname{subparagraph}{Subparagraph}{Subparagraphs}
}{}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}

First ref: \cref{sec:one}

Second ref: \cref{sec:two}

\section{One 1}
\label{sec:one}

\paragraph{Two}
\label{sec:two}

\end{document}
```

I understand that `\selectlanguage{english}` is too late and the last language from `\RequirePackage[english,ngerman]{babel}` is chosen. Is there a way to select english, without manipulating the preamble?

Comment: `article`  is no known option to `llncs`, also use `\usepackage{cleveref}` and not `\RequirePackage{cleveref}` in the document domain. Using `\crefname{paragraph}{Abschnitt}{....}` etc. will lead to `Abschnitt` both for `\section` and `\paragraph`

Comment: And please provide a compilable document as well.

Comment: You should propably tell that package `iflang` is necessary for `\IfLanguageName`. However, using your information I build a MWE which does *not* show the behaviour you describe. You should give us a complete example file to reproduce the issue… BTW: ``llncs` is not a class present in a usual TeX distribution. So if the class is necessary to reproduce the behaviour youshould give a link to it as well

Comment: @clemens: I added a MWE

Comment: Isn't this answered here? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/248341/9075