# cleveref customization + otherlanguage + cref don't jive well together

Tags: environments, babel, cleveref, german, english

Feeding

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=168mm,paperheight=240mm,height=210mm,width=144mm,includeall=true,showframe,showcrop]{geometry}%%% have visual text and page borders
\usepackage[USenglish,main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman,noabbrev]{cleveref}%%% no abbreviations in general, but there are a few exceptions, e.g. abbreviating German “Abbildung”
\overfullrule=1mm%%% put a thick vertical bar to take notice of overfulls
\newcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{ und }%%% allow for a line break after “und”
\newcommand{\creflastconjunction}{ und }%%% allow for a line break after “und”
\newcommand{\crefpairgroupconjunction}{ und }%%% allow for a line break after “und”
\newcommand{\creflastgroupconjunction}{ und }%%% allow for a line break after “und”
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{ bis }%%% allow for a line break after “bis”
\crefname{figure}{Abb.}{Abbn.}
\crefformat{figure}{Abb.\@\penalty9999\ #2#1#3}%%% allow for a line break after "Abb." under a high penalty
\crefrangeformat{figure}{Abbn.\@\penalty9999\ #3#1#4 bis #5#2#6}%%% "Abb.", "Abbn.", or "Abbildgn."; all are correct in German. Allow for a line break after the abbreviation under a high penalty.
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chap}
\begin{figure}Zeichnung\caption{Caption}\end{figure}%
\begin{figure}Zeichnung\caption{Caption}\end{figure}%
\begin{figure}Zeichnung\caption{Caption}\end{figure}%
\begin{figure}Zeichnung\caption{Caption}\end{figure}%
\begin{figure}Zeichnung\caption{Caption}\end{figure}%
\begin{figure}Zeichnung\caption{Caption}\end{figure}%
\part{Teil}
\section{Sect}
\begin{figure}%
  Zeichnung%
  \caption{Caption}%
  \label{fig:OneSeven}%
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}%
  Zeichnung%
  \caption{Caption}%
  \label{fig:OneEight}%
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}%
  Zeichnung%
  \caption{Caption}%
  \label{fig:OneNine}%
\end{figure}
EinLangesWort EinLangesWort LangesWort Wort \cref{fig:OneNine,fig:OneTen,fig:OneSeven,fig:OneEleven}.

\begin{otherlanguage}{USenglish}%%% The starred version otherlanguage* instead of otherlanguage works fine, though.
  Anything between one line and half a page of English text, which may cross a page border.
\end{otherlanguage}%

EinLangesWort EinLangesWort einWort \cref{fig:OneNine,fig:OneTen,fig:OneSeven,fig:OneEleven}.
\begin{figure}%
  Zeichnung%
  \caption{Caption}%
  \label{fig:OneTen}%
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}%
  Zeichnung%
  \caption{Caption}%
  \label{fig:OneEleven}%
\end{figure}%
\end{document}
```

to `pdflatex` yields

[image: output with a nonabbreviated figure and no line break where we wish it to be]

German vocabulary for your reference: *und* = *and*, *bis* = *till*, *Abbildung* = *Figure*, *Zeichnung* = *drawing*, *ein* = *a* or *one*, *langes* = *long*, *Wort* = *word*.

As you see, there are two issues:

1. The German for *Figures* is abbreviated inconsistently. Before the `otherlanguage` environment starts, we get a short *Abbn.*, which we wish. However, after the `otherlanguage` environment is over, we get a full *Abbildungen*, which we don't wish.
2. Breaking after the conjunction is inconsistent. Before the `otherlanguage` environment starts, LaTeX happily breaks after the automatically created *und*; this behavior is intended. However, after the `otherlanguage` environment is over, LaTeX doesn't break after *und*; this behavior sucks.

Why does this happen?  Are we using the interfaces of the packages in some unintended way? Otherwise: who is the culprit?  Should we file a bug report against babel or cleveref or any other package?

Which workaround would incur as few side effects as possible in a mostly German document with a few dozens of US-English paragraphs:

1. the starred version

   ```
   \begin{otherlanguage*}
   \end{otherlanguage*}%
   ```

   instead of the nonstarred version

   ```
   \begin{otherlanguage}
   \end{otherlanguage}
   ```
2. enclosing the environment `\begin{otherlanguage}…\end{otherlanguage}` into `\begingroup…\endgroup`, or
3. enclosing the environment `\begin{otherlanguage}…\end{otherlanguage}` into a pair of braces `{…}`, or
4. … your choice … ?

Comment: well the language support of cleveref is somewhat restricted. While the docu claims that after a `\selectlanguage` to the main language the format is restored, this is actually not true. You need to add your definitions manually to the language switches, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252847/2388

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have to say I tried and failed on this one :-(. `\cref@addlanguagedefs{ngerman}{\newcommand{\crefpairconjunction}{ und }}` throws an error. I'm also unsure as which commands to put inside `\cref@addlanguagedefs{ngerman}{…}` and which to leave outside.