# How to automatically create an appropriate amount of horizontal space between a title and a page number in the table of contents when using svmono?

Tags: table-of-contents, sv-classes, lastpage, horizontal-spacing

Feeding

```
\documentclass[deutsch]{svmono}% taken from https://resource-cms.springernature.com/springer-cms/rest/v1/content/20566/data/monographs
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[helvratio=.9]{newtxtext}% we use this in a non-minimal example
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}% we use this in a non-minimal example
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{calc}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}% to which depth the titles should occur in the table of contents. 4 means: paragraph titles occur in the table of contents, but not subparagraph titles.
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}% to which depth the numbering should occur. 4 means: paragraphs are numbered but not subparagraphs.
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}%%% cf. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/252847
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\author{Autor}
\title{Titel}
\maketitle
\frontmatter
\makeatletter
%\renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{1.8em}%% standard is 1.55em. Works but is fixed and might need an adjustment when the number of pages changes.
%%% cumbersome:
% \newlength{\Tmp}
% \setlength{\Tmp}{\widthof{\pageref*{LastPage}} + \fontdimen2*2/3}%%% doesn't work, dunno why
% \setlength{\Tmp}{\widthof{\pageref*{LastPage}}+\widthof{\ }*2/3}
% \renewcommand{\@pnumwidth}{\Tmp}
\makeatother
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\setcounter{page}{400}
\part{xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxx}
\chapter{xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
\section{xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx}
\subsection{xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx}
\subsubsection{xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx}
\paragraph{xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxxx xxxxxxx}
\end{document}
```

to `pdflatex` yields the following table of contents:

[image: toc]

As we see, there's no horizontal space between the titles and the page numbers.  This sucks.

One way to add horizontal space is to manually set `\@pnumwidth` to a fixed length.  However, we would need to think of changing this macro each time the number of digits in the total-page count changes.

Another way is to compute the last page number, take its width, add, e.g., 2/3 of the width of a space, put this into a length, and assign this length to `\@pnumwidth`.  This seems overly cumbersome.  Is there any other, more elegant way to do this?  (I don't wish to use `tocloft` because it changes the defaults of the `svmono` class.) Do we really need `lastpage` or does `hyperref` itself compute the last-page number? Do we really need to allocate a temporary length just for the purpose of the computation?

In summary, how to concisely compute and add an appropriate amount of horizontal space between a title and a page number?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by the "right amount" of space. Are you after some minimal space before the page number? The regular typographic convention is that page numbers are aligned right, titles are aligned left and there is a minimal space between titles and page numbers.

Comment: @PeterWilson Some horizontal distance between titles and page numbers. There's no precise definition of how much "some" should be, IMHO. To my taste, anything between half of the usual-blank width and the usual-blank width would do. In my question, I arbitrarily chose 2/3 of the blank width. Perhaps, even (3/4 of the usual-blank width) plus(1/4 of the usual-blank width) minus (1/4 of the usual-blank width) would do.